Saving button in powershell add element [SOLVED]
I am currently writing a powershell script with Gui in order to assist me editing pop file for the MVM gamemode in TF2.
Currently the powershell script is capable of open the file and display every wavespawn in a secondary view like this :View demonstration
This is the script I wrote with different documentation and help
# Load Windows Forms Assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create the Form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "WaveSpawns"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600, 400)

# Create the ListBox for wave names
$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 300)

# Create the TextBox for wave details
$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(220, 10)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 300)
$textBox.Multiline = $true
$textBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"

# Create the Open File button
$openFileButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$openFileButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 320)
$openFileButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$openFileButton.Text = "Open File"

# Create the Save button
$saveButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$saveButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180, 320)
$saveButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$saveButton.Text = "Save"

# Add controls to the form
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.Controls.Add($openFileButton)
$form.Controls.Add($saveButton)

# Variable to hold the file path globally
$global:filePath = $null

# Function to show Open File Dialog
function Show-OpenFileDialog {
    $fileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $fileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    $fileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    return $fileDialog.FileName
}

# Function to load file content and populate the ListBox
function Load-FileContent {
    param (
        [string]$filePath,
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListBox]$listBox,
        [ref]$waveSpawnDetails
    )

    $global:fileContent = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw
    $waves = $global:fileContent -split "WaveSpawn"
    $listBox.Items.Clear()
    foreach ($wave in $waves) {
        if ($wave.Trim()) {
            if ($wave -match 'Name\s+(\w+)') {
                $waveName = $matches[1]
                if ($waveName) {
                    $listBox.Items.Add($waveName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $waveSpawnDetails.Value = $global:fileContent
}

# Initialize the waveSpawnDetails variable
$waveSpawnDetails = ""

# Event handler for ListBox item selection
$listBox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $selectedWave = $listBox.SelectedItem
    if ($selectedWave) {
        $waveContent = $global:fileContent -split "WaveSpawn" | Where-Object { $_ -match "Name\s+$selectedWave" }
        $textBox.Text = "WaveSpawn`n" + $waveContent
    }
})

# Event handler for Open File button
$openFileButton.Add_Click({
    $global:filePath = Show-OpenFileDialog
    if ($global:filePath) {
        Load-FileContent -filePath $global:filePath -listBox $listBox -waveSpawnDetails ([ref]$waveSpawnDetails)
    }
})

# Event handler for Save button
$saveButton.Add_Click({
    $selectedWave = $listBox.SelectedItem
    Write-Host "Save button clicked. Selected wave: $selectedWave"

    if ($selectedWave -and $textBox.Text) {
        # Prepare the modified content
        $modifiedContent = $textBox.Text
        Write-Host "Modified content: $modifiedContent"

        # Regular expression to find the specific WaveSpawn block by wave name
        $regexPattern = "WaveSpawn\s*\{[^}]*Name\s+$selectedWave[^}]*\}"
        Write-Host "Regex pattern: $regexPattern"
        
        # Replace the matched block with the modified content
        if ($global:fileContent -match $regexPattern) {
            $updatedContent = [regex]::Replace($global:fileContent, $regexPattern, $modifiedContent)
            Write-Host "Updated content: $updatedContent"

            # Write the updated content back to the file
            Set-Content -Path $global:filePath -Value $updatedContent -Force
            
            # Inform the user
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The wavespawn file has been updated successfully.")
        } else {
            Write-Host "Could not find the wave block in the file."
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Could not find the wave block in the file.")
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "Please select a wave and make sure the text box is not empty."
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a wave and make sure the text box is not empty.")
    }
})

# Show the form
[void]$form.ShowDialog()

My issue is with the save button, every time I click on it the script will save the modification but also add everything that under the wavespawn instead of just modifying the wavespawn
Example of the issue
What is wrong with the argument I use in the script ?
I didn't try to do some massive change to fix the issue I've been mostly endlessy looking at the powershell documentation and asking questions.
Nota that the code doesn't give any error
You can use this dummy pop code to run some test
//This mission is a dummy mission and is probably not working, it just here to test the powershell script in "real condition"

#base robot_standard.pop
#base robot_giant.pop


WaveSchedule
{
    StartingCurrency 900
    RespawnWaveTime 4
    CanBotsAttackWhileInSpawnRoom no
    
    Mission
    {
        Objective   DestroySentries
        BeginAtWave 1
        RunForThisManyWaves 3
        InitialCooldown 30
        CooldownTime    30
        DesiredCount    1
        Where   spawnbot_mission_sentrybuster
        
        TFBot
        {
            Template    T_TFBot_SentryBuster
        }
    }   
    
    Wave    //wave 1    
    {

        StartWaveOutput
        {
            Target  wave_start_relay
            Action  Trigger
        }
        DoneOutput
        {
            Target  wave_finished_relay
            Action  Trigger
        }
        
        WaveSpawn







        {
            Name    wave1
            TotalCurrency   300
            TotalCount  4
            MaxActive   6
            SpawnCount  1
            WaitBeforeStarting  0
            WaitBetweenSpawns   12
            Where   spawnbot

            TFBot
            {
                Template    T_TFBot_Giant_Soldier
                Tag bot_giant
                Attributes  AlwaysFireWeapon
            }   
        }
    }           
}   

I would like to point out, TF2 pop file rules and syntax cannot be adapted, it is hard coded.
EDIT
The script is now working as intended, the save button does not add new caractere to the pop file
If anyone want, you may use this code and adapt it, if you want.
# Load Windows Forms Assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create the Form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "WaveSpawns"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600, 400)

# Create the ListBox for wave names
$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 300)

# Create the TextBox for wave details
$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(220, 10)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 300)
$textBox.Multiline = $true
$textBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"

# Create the Open File button
$openFileButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$openFileButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 320)
$openFileButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$openFileButton.Text = "Open File"

# Create the Save button
$saveButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$saveButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180, 320)
$saveButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$saveButton.Text = "Save"

# Add controls to the form
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.Controls.Add($openFileButton)
$form.Controls.Add($saveButton)

# Variable to hold the file path globally
$global:filePath = $null
$global:fileContent = $null

# Function to show Open File Dialog
function Show-OpenFileDialog {
    $fileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $fileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    $fileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    return $fileDialog.FileName
}

# Function to load file content and populate the ListBox
function Load-FileContent {
    param (
        [string]$filePath,
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListBox]$listBox
    )

    $global:fileContent = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw
    $listBox.Items.Clear()
    $waveBlocks = $global:fileContent -split '(?=\bWaveSpawn\b)'
    foreach ($waveBlock in $waveBlocks) {
        if ($waveBlock -match 'Name\s+(\w+)') {
            $waveName = $matches[1]
            if ($waveName) {
                $listBox.Items.Add($waveName)
            }
        }
    }
}

# Event handler for ListBox item selection
$listBox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $selectedWave = $listBox.SelectedItem
    if ($selectedWave) {
        $waveBlocks = $global:fileContent -split '(?=\bWaveSpawn\b)'
        foreach ($waveBlock in $waveBlocks) {
            if ($waveBlock -match "Name\s+$selectedWave") {
                $textBox.Text = "WaveSpawn" + $waveBlock.Substring($waveBlock.IndexOf("{"))
                break
            }
        }
    }
})

# Event handler for Open File button
$openFileButton.Add_Click({
    $global:filePath = Show-OpenFileDialog
    if ($global:filePath) {
        Load-FileContent -filePath $global:filePath -listBox $listBox
    }
})

# Event handler for Save button
$saveButton.Add_Click({
    $selectedWave = $listBox.SelectedItem
    Write-Host "Save button clicked. Selected wave: $selectedWave"

    if ($selectedWave -and $textBox.Text) {
        # Prepare the modified content
        $modifiedContent = $textBox.Text
        Write-Host "Modified content: $modifiedContent"

        # Split the file content by WaveSpawn
        $waveBlocks = $global:fileContent -split '(?=\bWaveSpawn\b)'
        $newContent = ""

        # Process each block and update the specific WaveSpawn block
        $updated = $false
        foreach ($waveBlock in $waveBlocks) {
            if ($waveBlock -match "Name\s+$selectedWave" -and -not $updated) {
                $newContent += "WaveSpawn" + $modifiedContent.Substring($modifiedContent.IndexOf("{")) + "`r`n"
                $updated = $true
            } else {
                $newContent += $waveBlock
            }
        }

        Write-Host "Updated content: $newContent"

        # Write the updated content back to the file
        Set-Content -Path $global:filePath -Value $newContent -Force
        
        # Inform the user
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The wavespawn file has been updated successfully.")
    } else {
        Write-Host "Please select a wave and make sure the text box is not empty."
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a wave and make sure the text box is not empty.")
    }
})

# Show the form
[void]$form.ShowDialog()


You need to rethink how you parse the WaveSpawn blocks from the source code. Right now your pattern only matches up to the first }, so any nested blocks will truncate the captured value

@Mathias R. Jessen
I can't change the language it is hard coded

I don't understand why that's relevant - it's the $regexPattern value in the PowerShell script you need to rethink :)

Ah my bad, what would be your suggestion about it ?

Let's have a look at what your regex pattern actually matches - I'll use a smaller version of the sample input you've posted for brevity here:
$inputString = @'
        WaveSpawn
        {
            Name    wave1
            TotalCurrency   300
            TotalCount  4

            TFBot
            {
                Template    T_TFBot_Giant_Soldier
            }   
        }
'@

$selectedWave = 'wave1'

$regexPattern = "WaveSpawn\s*\{[^}]*Name\s+$selectedWave[^}]*\}"

if ($inputString -match $regexPattern) {
  # output the matched substring
  $Matches[0]
}

Running this code will reveal the problem:
WaveSpawn
        {
            Name    wave1
            TotalCurrency   300
            TotalCount  4

            TFBot
            {
                Template    T_TFBot_Giant_Soldier
            }

The part of the original string that's matched stops at the first }, meaning you won't be overwriting the closing }'s once [regex]::Replace runs, and thus you end up with repetitions of the trailing }'s.
Change your regex pattern to match until the curly brackets are balanced, meaning we've reached the } corresponding to the { immediately after WaveSpawn:
$regexPattern = "WaveSpawn\s*\{([^}]*Name\s+$selectedWave(?:[^{}]|(?<depth>\{)|(?<-depth>\}))+(?(depth)(?!)))\}"

You'll notice I've replaced the last [^}]* with the following expression:
(?:[^{}]|(?<depth>\{)|(?<-depth>\}))+(?(depth)(?!))

The first part, (?:[^{}]|(?<depth>\{)|(?<-depth>\}))+, will first attempt to consume any non-brackets ([^{}]). If that fails, it'll attempt to match a literal { and push it onto a capture stack named depth ((?<depth>\{)). If that fails too, it'll capture a } and then remove the last value from the capture stack named depth.
The second part, (?(depth)(?!)) is a conditional group - if any values are still associated with the depth stack, ?! will ensure a match failure - meaning the match can only end once the final closing } is observed.
Running the same code as above with the new pattern gives us the expected value:
WaveSpawn
        {
            Name    wave1
            TotalCurrency   300
            TotalCount  4

            TFBot
            {
                Template    T_TFBot_Giant_Soldier
            }
        }

Meaning that [regex]::Replace should now be able to replace the whole block, not just the part up until the first }

Very good answer, I would like to point out something, editing the regex does work on the last part of the code but if I have a wavespawn before it the same issue and the other wavespawn just get copied, maybe I have to do two different regex expression instead

@Maselia That'd be a better (and likely faster) approach indeed. Split the input string by (?=WaveSpawn), then apply the suggested pattern to each individual substring :)

Finish, the script is now working, I will edit my post one last time and accept your solution @Mathias R. Jessen
